# Want to make social login with Loopback and Loopback angularjs-sdk?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, facebook, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using loopback and as a backend framework in my application. And loopback-angular-SDK for the front end. I want to make social login i.e. login by facebook and google. I don't know where to start.

I've gone thru this https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport link but it is using angular SDK.

Please guide me how can I do this.

Comment: loopback-example-passport is fully on REST. You can make your request on `/auth/facebook` and get the success/error url configured in passport configuration. You can then filter out access token back to the client app.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use it with angular js SDk

Comment: Well, it is completely possible, pls refer this https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/issues/102#issuecomment-157052760

Comment: and also this, https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-angular/issues/74#issuecomment-57164643

Comment: @anoop somehow I'm not able to get it. It will be helpful if you provide a sample that how it should be, if it is possible for you.

Comment: I have done it using a ReactJs client not with Angular. But I suppose this question is something related to what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213792/login-by-facebook-in-angular-app-with-loopback-backend